# Summing query results based on another column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi I have this sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzKlEAF5IcZehmyyRUQ5ELE63Q-ZVfp9Nfx5-zvKAOc/edit?usp=sharing

I want to pull the data from the left chart. Then I want to sum Same companies revenues. Then I want to put that data dynamically to the right part. I also want to be able to check how much revenue I got from each company each month. I also want to see top 5 companies who made purchase in each month.

So for example: If Company A made 3 purchases in January I want to see sum of these purchases next to company name and sort companies from highest money to lowest for each month.

I wrote a function for that but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you used to write the function? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does your function throw an error or it just don't do what you expect?

Comment: I use google sheet functions to do that. And I presume functions are quite enough for that purpose. The function that i wrote shows top 5 purchases but I want it to combine purchases made by same company and show the results after.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and wanted to share here in case anyone would need in the future. This answer belongs to [Greg from Google Docs community](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!profile/docs/APn2wQcTOXnD0xre1oZn1dEAIx5Rb8UwvD-yYSPhP6rTIbnviAsqTWVVJ_oqEu-NeOk9GAPH4zzg). I will copy paste the exact answer here:

> Hello, See sheet [GE.Sheet1.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzKlEAF5IcZehmyyRUQ5ELE63Q-ZVfp9Nfx5-zvKAOc/edit?usp=sharing) I have added the formulas to demonstrate
>   your requests.
>
> I want to pull the data from the left chart. Then I want to sum
>   Same companies revenues. Then I want to put that data dynamically to
>   the right part.
>
> =QUERY(A:C,"select B, sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 1)
>   =QUERY(A:C,"select B, A, sum(C) where B is not null group by B, A", 1)
>
> I also want to be able to check how much revenue I got from each
>   company each month. I also want to see the top 5 companies who made
>   a purchase in each month.
>
> =QUERY(A:C,"select B, sum(C) where A = '" & M1 & "' and B is not null group by B, A order by sum(C) desc label sum(C) ''", 0)
>
> A limit clause can be added but there is not enough data to test
>   against. Need more than 5 clients and multiple months.
>
> bests,
>
> GregE